# Android facebook detect first login

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using facebook login for my android app, now to create a user in MYSQL database I want to know when the user first logs in the app..

Something like, when we authorize the app to use facebook basic info.

Thanks :)

Edit: I'm using a Facebook login button (`<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton... />`) for login & I'm fetching the user details when the statechanges, using

```
onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception){...}
```

Comment: Can you not just add the user id to the mysql database after you get a success message from facebook? Just use their facebook id as the uique identifier?

Comment: On the authorization you use a Listener. At the OnComplete Method of that listener you can execute your SQL query to add the user in your Database!

Comment: @alistair3408, your suggestion seems good, I just have one doubt, will it create any problem when the number of users increases ??

Comment: @Παύλος, I'm doing that, I just want some way through which I should know that the user is using the app for the first time & I should register him.

Comment: @Παύλος, I mean when the user is logging in to Facebook for the first time **using my app**

Comment: Instantiate a SharedPreference boolean and do checks on it! For example when a user has logged in using your app just make it true. So that you know if it is false he/she hasnt connected to Fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store whether or not the app has been run before in something called "[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)". You can use something like the following

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(prefs.contains(HAS_BEEN_RUN_FLAG)){
    //check the database for the user info
}
else{            
    //do the facebook authentication
    prefs.edit().putInt(HAS_BEEN_RUN_FLAG, 1).commit();
}
```